# How to get the current live steams of a channel that is not my own?

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I have been navigating through the API with no luck. I'm trying to extract the current live streams of channel which is not my own.

I did something similar where I extracted all the uploaded videos of a channel using the `playlistItems` call of the Data API, I tried to do something similar for the livestreams with no luck whatsoever.

Is there any possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the [`liveBroadcast`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts) or [`liveStream`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams) object that does not belong to the user or channel you are authenticated as.  The `list` endpoint for each object requires your to authenticate as your own channel/user to retrieve your own live events only.

If you want to retrieve information on another channel's broadcast, you have to use the standard [`Search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint.  This will return return only live events from a particular channel, without being authenticated as that channel/user, if you know that channel's `channelId`:

`part -> snippet`

`channelId` -> `[channelId of the channel/user with the live event]`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```